Maximum weight edge in a cycle and Minimum Spanning Tree
Consider G a simple, connected, undirected graph. I know there exists a property called cut property, which states that for a given cut $(S, G-S)$, if an edge $e$ crossing that cut from $S$ to $G-S$ has minimum weight among all the other crossing edges in this cut, then $e$ belongs to the minimum spanning tree of $G$.
Is it valid to state the following: "if for any cut $(S,G-S)$, $e$ is not a minimum crossing edge, then $e$ is not in the MST" ?
I considered this to be true to prove that any maximum edge in a cycle of different edges cannot be in the MST. I know the statement I provided is the converse of the cut property, I actually don't know if it is correct.

I think the condition provided in the statement for any cut is a very strong one. In particular, as both $S$ and $G-S$ are always connected components, they could always can be made trees $S^$ and $(G-S)^$ by cycle edges removals, so $S^* \cup (G-S)^* + e$ is a Spanning Tree for any crossing edge $u$. Because there always exists a crossing edge $u$ with weight less than $e$, then $e$ can never be in spanning trees formed in this way. What I'm missing?

I think the statement is sufficient for $e$ not being in any MST. If $e$ is not minimal for any cut, then we can conclude more easily by contradiction: If $T$ is a MST with the edge $e$ in question, then $T-e$ gives a cut ($T_1$, $T_2$), as $e$ crosses that cut and is not the minimal weight edge by hypothesis, then we can pick other edge $u$ with weight less than $e$, $T_1 \cup T_2 \cup u$ gives a spanning tree with total weight less than the first one, a contradiction.
